# TabBarViewController in XCode 8 have a big blue Screen

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, xcode8

I don't know what happen. I just drag UITab and drop in Storyboard and don't let me work.

Somebody know any workaround?

I use clear color in Global Tint property but just change the color. I can not work inside the View.

[image]

Comment: can you share code or constraint screen shoot

Comment: Thank you for your comment, after this, I try with a fresh a new storyboard and apparently does not have this problem. Maybe is because I reuse an old Storyboard and delete another thing and maybe stay with trash. Thanks @chirag

Comment: My happiness just happen until open a close the new storyboard. After create it just change to another storyboard inside in the same project and return to this new storyboard and return the blue screen :( . So I will looking for some workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it but I don't know why.

I try with a fresh a new storyboard and apparently does not have this problem. Maybe is because I reuse an old Storyboard and delete another thing and maybe stay with trash.